# Consume and validate JWT in Open Liberty

Tags: jwt, open-liberty

I'm trying to use the jwt-1.0 feature in Open Liberty.

The JwtBuilder API is pretty nice and allows to set expiration, sign, encrypt and build a token programmatically (and everything else needed).

```
JwtBuilder.create().expirationTime(expTime).signWith(signAlg, privateKey).encryptWith(keyMgmtAlg, keyMgmtKey, contentEncAlg).buildJwt().compact();
```

But the JwtConsuer API seems pretty lame and only allows to read a token without validation at all.

```
JwtConsumer.create().createJwt(token);
```

Signature validation and decryption should be configured through the application server configuration (via "jwtConsumer" and "keystore" entries) but it's not possible programmatically.
I should accommodate with this but other validations like expiration date are not possible.

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct in that the `JwtConsumer` API does not provide a programmatic way to set specific validation requirements. However the JWT will still be validated when `createJwt()` is called.

The `JwtConsumer` API's `create()` and `create(String consumerConfigId)` methods tie the `JwtConsumer` object to a `<jwtConsumer>` element in the server configuration that specifies the validation requirements. The configuration settings for that element can be viewed here: https://openliberty.io/docs/22.0.0.4/reference/config/jwtConsumer.html.

The `JwtConsumer.create()` method will use the default `<jwtConsumer>` configuration that is provided automatically by the runtime, which simply looks like this:

```
<jwtConsumer id="defaultJwtConsumer" />
```

Similarly, the `JwtConsumer.create(String consumerConfigId)` would use the configuration with the corresponding ID. So `JwtConsumer.create("myJwtConsumer")` would use the corresponding "myJwtConsumer" configuration in the server.xml. That could look something like this:

```
<jwtConsumer id="myJwtConsumer"
    issuer="https://example.com"
    audiences="Luke, Leia, Han"
    signatureAlgorithm="RS256"
    jwkEnabled="true"
    jwkEndpointUrl="https://..."
/>
```

You'd put whatever validation settings you want in that configuration. Then when you call `JwtConsumer.createJwt(token)`, the runtime will perform several validation checks against the JWT. That includes checking the issuer, audiences, `iat` and `exp` times, the `nbf` claim, and of course the signature of the token.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Yes, that's I wanted to say when I wrote "should be configured through the application server configuration" but I haven't found a corresponding attribute on the "jwtConsumer" entry to define validation of iat or exp. Can you point me to it ? Is it "clockSkew" ?

Comment: Ok, I've checked and setting a value for the "clockSkew" attribute activate expiration validation on the consumer. Thank you !

Comment: The `iat` and `exp` claims should automatically be validated by the `JwtConsumer` without you having to configure anything; it will essentially validate that `iat` <= now <= `exp`. The `clockSkew` attribute is just there to account for minor differences in time between system clocks. If you're wanting a more granular check like "exp isn't 18 years in the future," then no, there isn't a way to configure that. You can, however, do additional programmatic checks on the `JwtToken` that's returned from `JwtConsumer.createJwt()`. You can call `JwtToken.getClaims()` and do whatever checks you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer, if a clockSkew is not specified, then a default value of 5 minutes is used. On the other hand, setting clockSkew="0m" will in effect disable the clock skew.

Comment: Oh, OK ! Thanks for the clarification, I've missed the default value in the documentation...